# What is the best place to find a great javascript programmer

Tags: freelance-websites, programmer, web-development

Which is the best place to find javascript programmer on hourly basis, that can code in javascript at a professional level.

Comment: In 90% of pubs in Shoreditch? But seriously, try advertising on freelance job boards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've hired 3 people from https://www.f6s.com/ recently.

It's a busy startup community with both technical and business type people actively looking for opportunities, and it costs nothing to post jobs.